# Android app notification: "From GCM: server deleted 149 pending messages"

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I just received a notification from the SE Android app saying:

```
From GCM: server deleted 149 pending messages!
```

Is this a bug? I consider it to be one.

Comment: Oops! That should only be showing up in developer versions of the app,  it's a helper for us but meaningless to anyone else!

Comment: I guessed it's something like that.

Comment: Hmm. As many as 149, sounds serious! :)

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi So... does that mean the dev mod is hidden in the existing app? *starts searching*

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed for version 1.0.13, thanks!

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!